# Enabling OCS Inventory WebService interface for querying assets data

Tags: php, linux, apache, perl, perl-module

How to enable the OCS Inventory interface described in [OCS WebServices](http://wiki.ocsinventory-ng.org/index.php/Developers:Web_services)? Is there a sample code for using this Web Service in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OCS interface is disabled by default, it is necessary to turn it on before use it. OCS has a core code developed in Perl and it runs over Apache HTTP.

First, edit the file `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/z-ocsinventory-server.conf` changing the option value for `OCS_OPT_WEB_SERVICE_ENABLED` to *1*.
If the web service is not enabled you should get a *401 Forbidden* response. This is a SOAP WebService and there's no WSDL to describe the features, just the docs available in [OCS WS Documentation](http://wiki.ocsinventory-ng.org/index.php/Developers:Web_services).

Check if the location tag for */ocsinterface* looks like the following snippet:

```
 <Location /ocsinterface>
      SetHandler perl-script
      PerlHandler Apache::Ocsinventory::SOAP
      # By default, you can query web service from everywhere with a valid user
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "OCS Inventory SOAP Area"
      # Use htpasswd to create/update soap-user (or another granted user)
      AuthUserFile "/etc/apache2/passwd/soapinterface"
      Require valid-user
 </Location>
```

You should create a password for this location for security purposes, however, to turn the authentication off just comment out all ***Auth...*** and ***Require*** attributes.

Restart apache server, and use the PHP code below to test the web service integration

```
<?php
$proto = 'http';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = '80';
$user = ''; //basic authentication, if necessary
$pass = ''; 

$options = array(
    'location' => "$proto://$host:$port/ocsinterface",
    'uri' => "$proto://$host:$port/Apache/Ocsinventory/Interface",
    'login' => $user,
    'password' => $pass,
    'trace' => TRUE,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
);

$request = '
        <REQUEST>
            <ENGINE>FIRST</ENGINE>
            <ASKING_FOR>META</ASKING_FOR>
            <CHECKSUM>131071</CHECKSUM>
            <OFFSET>0</OFFSET>
            <WANTED>131071</WANTED>
        </REQUEST>';

try {
    $client = new SoapClient(NULL, $options);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<b>Construct Error</b>: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
}

try {
    $result = $client->get_computers_V1($request);
    echo "<b>Headers:</b><pre>" . $client->__getLastRequestHeaders() . " </pre><br>";
    echo "<b>Request:</b><pre>" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "</pre><br>";
    echo "<b>Result:</b><pre>";
    var_dump($result);
    echo "</pre><br>";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<b>Connection Error</b>: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br><br>";
    echo "<b>Headers:</b><pre>\r\n" . $client->__getLastRequestHeaders() . " </pre><br>";
echo "<b>Request:</b><pre>\r\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "</pre>";
}
```

---

If you get a ***HTTP 500 Internal Server Error***, check apache error log (`tail -f  /var/log/apache2/error.log -n 100`) for the following error message:

> Illegal field name 'APR::Table=HASH(0x7ff114bd75a8)' at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/SOAP/Transport/HTTP2.pm line 103.\n

That error happens due to an incompatibility issue found in HTTP::Message perl module. The following links describes the problem and solution related to it:

1. http://ask.ocsinventory-ng.org/735/demande-dinformations-web-service-ocs-inventory
2. https://www.tnpi.net/support/forums/index.php?topic=1037.0

To fix it, you need to downgrade the HTTP::Message perl module to version **6.04**. Use the command `cpan -D HTTP::Message` in your console to check which version you're using. This module version is a little bit old, so you won't find it in [Search CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/). In this regard, you should download the module [HTTP-Message-6.04.tar.gz](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/repo/pkgs/perl-HTTP-Message/HTTP-Message-6.04.tar.gz/d3cedbb4b1ca476ab2b0a70b5c289fe1/HTTP-Message-6.04.tar.gz) and install it manually by typing the following commands on your terminal:

1. decompress it using `tar -zxf HTTP-Message-6.04.tar.gz`
2. call the new directory `cd HTTP-Message-6.04/`
3. `perl Makefile.PL`
4. `make`
5. `make test`
6. `make install`
7. and finally, check if the module got downgraded successfully by typing `cpan -D HTTP::Message`(it should output *... Installed: 6.04 ...*)
8. restart the server - `service apache2 restart`

Run the PHP snippet shown above to test it again.